# handler not given exact time interval

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application, I'm using a handler to update date and time. It updates date & time but not given the accurate result. Like if I set to update after 60 seconds, it update after 62 seconds. If I update it to 120 sec, it update after 2 min 2 sec.
Kindly help me why it is talking more time?
My code is

```
public static String interval = "60";

        Handler h2 = new Handler();
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyLocation loc = new MyLocation(getBaseContext());
            TextView longitude_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GPS_Long_txta);
            ((TextView) longitude_view)
                    .setText(" " + String.valueOf(loc.gps_lon));
            TextView latitude_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GPS_Lat_txta);
            ((TextView) latitude_view).setText(" " + String.valueOf(loc.gps_lat));
            long delaytime = (RestoreRecord0()*1000);
            last_update_time_txtbx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_txt);
            last_update_time_txtbx.setText(" "
                    + String.valueOf(java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                            .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())));
            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String response = CallWebService(tm.getDeviceId(), loc.gps_lon, loc.gps_lat);
            h2.postDelayed(this, delaytime);
        }
    };
```

Here is a method `RestoreRecord0`

```
public int RestoreRecord0() {
        try {

            File dir = getFilesDir();
            File file = new File(dir, Saveinterval);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                return Integer.parseInt(interval);
            }

            FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fileIS));
            String readString = new String();
            String data = "";
            // just reading each line and pass it on the debugger

            while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                data += readString;
            }

            return Integer.parseInt(data);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(interval);
    }
```

Kindly help. How to update of time at regular and accurate interval?

Comment: What is the value of `RestoreRecord0()`? Have you timed how long it takes for your Runnable to complete? Lastly, have you tried `postAtTime()` to remove any running delay?

Comment: in RestoreRecord0() i save value of interval which user set.

Comment: where i use postAtTime(). after h2.postDelayed(this,delaytime)?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that are incorrect and won't meet the desired result if you really want it to be real-time update because:

1. All updates that happen through the `Handler` are bound for some delay - due to the inherent framework code
2. Your `handler` code is way too much cluttered. Please simplify it.

What I can recommend on the handler side:

1. Instead of doing all `findViewById` etc - have the references alrady ready and just do `setText` of all the text views
2. That also means to remove the file operation - Not sure, how it really helps , if you dont want it to persist for long time; then use `handler.sendMessage` it has 2 `Object` types, where you can set any custom DataModel and pass the update times - much more efficient too